# s there any way I can tell Ansible to execute the command exactly as I have given?

Tags: ansible

I have a simple command with grep and perl regex to extract `catalina.home` from `ps -ef | grep java` output, as below.

```
ps -ef |grep java |grep -Po "Dcatalina.home=[^\s]*\s"
```

And when I execute this command it will extract only cataline.home part from the output as below.

```
# ps -ef |grep java |grep -Po "Dcatalina.home=[^\s]*\s"
Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.32
```

But when I issue the same command via Ansible, its sending to server as
`ps -ef |grep java |grep -Po /\"Dcatalina.home=[^/\\s]*\/\s\"` and gives no output.

Error from Ansible

```
FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cd $(ps -ef |grep java |grep -Po \"Dcatalina.home=[^\\s]*\\s\" | awk -F'=' '{print $2}') ; bash bin/version.sh | grep 'Server version:'", "delta": "0:00:00.080606", "end": "2017-08-17 03:57:02.816848", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2017-08-17 03:57:02.736242", "stderr": "/bin/sh: line 0: cd: [^\\s]*\\s\": No such file or directory\nbash: bin/version.sh: No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: line 0: cd: [^\\s]*\\s\": No such file or directory", "bash: bin/version.sh: No such file or directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Is there any way I can tell Ansible to execute the command exactly as I have given?

Comment: Which module do you use? As far as I remember the shell module http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/shell_module.html  is better to execute commands.

Comment: @ThoFin I am using shell module only. 

`shell: cd $(ps -ef |grep java |grep -Po "Dcatalina.home=[^\s]*\s" | awk -F'=' '{print $2}') ; bash bin/version.sh | grep 'Server version:'
        register: cnp_tomcat_output
`

Comment: whats with the weird forward slashes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it is working on me:

```
$ ansible server-1.infra.local -i server/hosts -m shell -a 'ps -ef |grep java | grep -Po "Dcatalina.home[^\s]*\s"' -K --become-method=sudo -b -k

SSH password: 
SUDO password[defaults to SSH password]: 
server-1.infra.local | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
```